# utop - command not found

Tags: ocaml, utop

Suddenly when trying to use utop on my macbook, I get the error in the title. I've tried reinstalling with opam and reinstalling with homebrew but I've had no success. I haven't changed anything, this just randomly started happening. Has anyone had this problem?

Edit: I used `brew install opam` to install opam but I get an error: `Warning: git 2.15.1 is already installed
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!`
This could be a different issue all together but I'm not sure

Comment: eval \`opam config env\`

Comment: @Julian Fondren no good.

Comment: Could you provide more information? How did you install opam? Did you run `opam init`? Did you install `utop`? What is your current `PATH`?

Comment: @Rizo updated question. I did run `opam init`, here is my PATH: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. Do I need to add git to it?

Comment: Your PATH does not contain the opam binary directory. It should contain something like: `/Users/<username>/.opam/4.05.0/bin:...`. Which shell are you using? I recommend following this instructions to make sure your env is properly configured: https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions